# Couldn't find that process type (web) when deploying spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I have a `spring boot` application which works locally. I would like to deploy on `heroku`. I followed the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) but I it did not work and I got `"No web processes running"` error.
Follwing the suggested solutions, I tried `>heroku ps:scale web=1` and I got `Couldn't find that process type` error.
Then, I tried the following commands:

`heroku buildpacks:clear`

`heroku buildpacks:add heroku/java`

`git commit --allow-empty -m "Adjust buildpacks on Heroku"`

`git push heroku master`

But the problem is still there.
Here is my `pom.xml` if it helps:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tests4geeks.tutorials</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mongo-tutorial</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.11.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
     <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

output of `build`:

```
Enumerating objects: 277, done.
Counting objects: 100% (277/277), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (259/259), done.
Writing objects: 100% (277/277), 157.87 MiB | 1.29 MiB/s, done.
Total 277 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
remote: -----> Executing Maven
remote:        $ mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
remote:        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
remote:        [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom
remote:        [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom (8.6 kB at 13 kB/s)
remote:        [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom
remote:        [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom (122 kB at 1.4 MB/s)
remote:        [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/datastax/oss/java-driver-bom/4.6.1/java-driver-bom-4.6.1.pom
remote:        [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/datastax/oss/java-driver-bom/4.6.1/java-driver-bom-4.6.1.pom (3.8 kB at 251 kB/s)

remote:        [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_84b248db/target/mongo-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/tests4geeks/tutorials/mongo-tutorial/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mongo-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
remote:        [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_84b248db/pom.xml to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/tests4geeks/tutorials/mongo-tutorial/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mongo-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  26.956 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-26T20:53:46Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 211.1M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://hidden-coast-44319.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/hidden-coast-44319.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your buildpacks, and I don't think your `pom.xml` is relevant either (though I'm not a Java dev). Do you have a `Procfile`? What does it contain? I assume since you are trying to use `heroku/java` that you're not deploying with Docker?

Comment: @Chris I am not using Docker. You're right. Regarding the Procfile, I don't have any and it seems that it is not necessary. In the link I shared (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) the application is correctly deployed without needing a Procfile.

Comment: I'm not clear how process types are mapped if you don't have a `Procfile`. Please [edit] your question to show us the full build output from when you push.

Comment: @Chris I also tried with a Procfile containing "web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.jar" but it didn't help and I got another error: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/*.jar

Comment: Okay, well, that's a different problem. Please [edit] your question to show your build output as I asked earlier or ask a _new_ question about your problem with your `Procfile`.

Comment: @Chris I updated the question with the output of the build process. However, it is not the whole output as it was more than 60000 lines which was more than the allowed amount for a question on Stackoverflow. I think it includes the relevant part. In the meantime, after the build process, I see a war file in my target folder.

Comment: Do you _have_ a `Procfile`? Even an empty one? The build output says `Procfile declares types -> (none)`, but I'm not seeing the `Default types for buildpack -> web` line from the documentation you linked. Try `heroku buildpacks:clear` and then (without explicitly setting one) deploying again.

Comment: @Chris No, I don't have any Procfile at all. I tried `heroku buildpacks:clear` and then `git push heroku master`. Was that what you meant? Unfortunately, it also didn't help.

Comment: @Chris In the documentation there is a line `spring init --dependencies=web demo`. As I am not creating a new project, I have skipped it. Should I have used the  `--dependencies=web` somewhere else? If yes, could you please tell me how?

Comment: I think that's a different kind of `web`. It probably adds some configuration or dependencies for creating web applications. Since you were able to get a different error by adding a `Procfile`, I suggest you do that and continue down the path of getting that working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it solved by adding a Procfile including the following text:

```
web: java -jar target/mongo-tutorial-1.0.jar
```

AND removing the following lines from the `pom` file:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```